# UILocalNotificationの通知から起動した際の動作設定

Tags: ios, objective-c

iPhoneアプリケーションがバックグラウンドの際にUILocalNotificationを利用して通知を送信し、その通知からアプリを起動した際に、特定のビューを表示したいと考えております。

現在、通知の開くを押すと、普通にアプリが起動し、アプリの最初の画面(ViewControler)を表示すると事までは完成しています。通知から起動した際に特定のビュー(SecondViewControler)などを表示するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

```
- (void)setLocalNotification:(NSString *)message
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.alertBody = message;
    notification.alertAction = @"開く";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // 通知を登録
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: Xcode自体についての質問ではないため、xcodeタグを削除しました。

Answer (score 2):

SecondViewControllerをモーダルで表示する場合のサンプルです。
`AppDelegate`に記述してください。

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  if (userInfo != nil) {
    [self showSecondViewController];
  }
  return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    [self showSecondViewController];
  }
}

- (void)showSecondViewController
{
  UIViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

StoryboardでデザインしたSecondViewControllerを表示するには以下のようにします。
`storyboardWithName:@"Main"`の部分は、該当するStoryboardのファイル名に依存するので適宜変えてください。(`Main.storyboard`の場合は`@"Main"`)

注意点として、Storyboard上でSecondViewControllerの`Storyboard ID`に`SecondViewController`をセットする必要があります。

```
- (void)showSecondViewController
{
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: 教えていただいた上記の方法で実装しましたが、通知をタップした後に黒い画面になってしまい動作しませんでした。

AppDelegateにはSecondViewControllerはImportしてあります。
他に何かありましたら教えてください。お願いします。

Comment: SecondViewControllerのデザインにはStoryBoardを利用していますか？

Comment: すべてStoryboardを利用しています。

Comment: Storyboardを利用する場合の回答を追加しました。

Comment: 無事に動作致しました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @TomoakiM.さん。無事に解決しましたら、この回答にチェックをつけることで解決済みを示すことができます。